# RecyclerView Remove/Add animations overlapping divider

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I would like to know if it's possible to have the add/remove animations not overlap the divider like in the following video:

https://www.grokkingandroid.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/recyclerview_animation.mp4?_=1

I am unsure as to how I can make the divider be bound to the item and not the view. Any help is useful.

Comment: An in-depth article including a demo project is all available on the website you're linking to. [A First Glance at Android’s RecyclerView](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the divider in SupportV7Demos app in AOSP. Basically, you should consider View's translateX/translateY properties when positioning your dividers.

Comment: Thank you, i looked into SupportV7Demos and helped us a lot!